# Xemacs does not show compilation errors anymore

Tags: emacs, xemacs

I know this sounds *really* stupid, but:

I used to compile an Android jni project under Xemacs. The only feature that I needed was the ability to locate the place reported by gcc in the source code, edit and save.

But now this does not work anymore. Probably Xemacs caught some keypresses intended for another window (that is, I did not mention which one has the focus) and switched into a different mode. When I restart Xemacs, it works initially and after a while stops working again.

Question: how do I make it functional again?

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you try this in GNU Emacs?  It seems you don't haven't
heavily customized XEmacs so switching shouldn't be painful.

I hope someone with XEmacs expertise can help you, but XEmacs has 13
*THIRTEEN* followers on Stackoverflow. Clearly your chances of getting help will
improve is you try the Emacs that more people use.